How can I start VS Code with maximized window in Ubuntu 24.04?
With Ubuntu 22.04 my Visual Studio Code always started with a maximized window.
Now, with using Ubuntu 24.04, I'm unable to start VS Code with a maximized window.
The system uses X11 as windowing system.

There are many layers to this.
By default, VSCode reloads the last closed window, restoring its state (size, position). However, that doesn't work if the window is closed while maximized; in that case, the previous window state is restored instead. I think this is a bug: it doesn't look intended, and I'm pretty sure it didn't use to be like that before.
Further evidence to this is the fact that setting "window.newWindowDimensions": "maximized" in settings.json also won't make new windows launch in a maximized state. So there might be something up with VSCode and maximized windows in general.
However, you can kinda work around this two different ways:

Hit F11 to enter fullscreen mode, then set "window.restoreFullscreen": true in settings.json. This works and correctly restores the last closed window to fullscreen mode. While in fullscreen mode, you can hit Alt to show the menu.
Use Zen mode (Ctrl+K / Z). This also works and correctly restores the last closed window to Zen mode. You shouldn't need to set "zenMode.restore": true in settings.json as that should be the default. While in Zen mode, you can hit Alt to show the menu. I'd encourage you to follow this path, customizing Zen mode to your liking (I think you could configure it to show everything that it normally hides if you really wanted to, so you wouldn't be forced to miss anything from the regular mode, unless you wanted to).

Here's my VSCode version for reference:
1.93.1
38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40
x64

